# What is the limit for async jobs in Facebook Python SDK?

Tags: python, facebook-python-business-sdk

I'm creating an async job with Facebook's Python SDK to get the insights (impressions, action_values, etc) for my Facebook campaigns. Right now I'd like to pull all the campaigns for the previous year by month. The total number of results should be around `2,000`. If I set the limit param in get_result to anything higher than *1000* I get a `FacebookRequestError`. The 
 async_job

(see code below) runs, and using

```
api_get()
```

I can tell that it pulls all the records. Is there anyway to pull all of the results from the `async_job`?

```
async_job = my_account.get_insights_async(fields=params.get('fields'), params=params)
async_job.api_get(
while async_job.api_get()['async_percent_completion'] < 100:
  time.sleep(1)
  async_job.api_get() 
data = async_job.get_result(params={'limit':1000})
```

Comment: I think you just need to call get_result multiple times and the api should give results in max 1000 record batches?

Comment: @TeemuIkonen I just tried that by creating a new variable called data2 and did the same same get_result call, but unfortunately they are identical. Maybe there's another way to get the next 1000 responses?  Maybe an additional paramter in the get_result function